# Python command fails to restart linux service

Tags: python, linux, windows, service, systemctl

I have this **python** code on my **windows machine** that gets the status of a **service** on my **linux server**:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('MY_HOST', username='MY_USER', password='MY_PASS')

stdin, stdout, _stderr = client.exec_command('systemctl status example.service')

print(_stdout.read())

client.close()
```

But when I switch from **"systemctl status"** to **"systemctl restart"** to **restart the service** nothing happens and the service doesn't restart!

Am I doing something **wrong**? Is there **another way** to restart a linux service using python code on my windows machine? **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `systemctl restart` just returns, it doesn't write anything to stdout nor stderr. You should always check the `systemctl status` to actually see what's happening after the restart.

Comment: @h4z3 Yes I know, but when I check the status I see that the restart didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that I **wasn't logged in with the root user**, so I changed the **ssh configuration** to **login directly** with the root user and the restart worked!

**1** - First, enable ROOT by running this command "**sudo passwd root**", then enter the password and then confirm!

**2** - Now, let's edit the file that will enable SSH access in Ubuntu with this command "**vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config**"!

**3** - Look for this part of the code and leave it like this:

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
```

4 - Finally restart the SSHD service with this command "**sudo systemctl restart ssh**" and that's it!